# Keyword search excel

Tags: excel, search, keyword, matching

So I am terrible with excel and my current job requires me to comb through a ton of data. Here's what I am trying to do... I have about 40 pages of data in an excel sheet - it contains about 200 different programs and what each is capable of doing. Then, I have a separate list of people's problems that our programs may be able to help solve. Both lists are written in paragraph format in a word doc, but I have moved it to excel.

I am trying to figure out a way to match just the name of the program to just the title of the problem, by searching/comparing the description of the problem with the description of our program. In the past, doing this manually has taken nearly 80 manhours and it just seems like a waste.

1. Is there even a way to do this?
2. How difficult would it be for an excel novice to do, seeing as it's on a standalone system - where I can't copy/paste here?

Thanks in advance for any help/advice. I tried to include examples.

**Customer problem**

[image]

**Potential solution**

[image]

Comment: Take a look at excel function. **Search** is a good one. https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/search.php

Comment: google ms fuzzy lookup

Comment: You should check out the find() function as well.

Comment: And you will want to create a mapping table of key words to program (i.e. those you will be searching for).